# How to load environment variables in Flask unit test

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest

I'm trying to test an app which relies on several environment variables (API keys, mostly). I'd like to keep those as variables instead of putting them directly into a config file, but my unit tests (using `unittest`) won't run because the environment variables aren't loaded when the test mounts.

I've tried calling `load_dotenv` in `setUp` (see below) but that doesn't make a difference. How can I ensure that the test suite reads the environment variables correctly?

**.flaskenv**

```
FLASK_APP=myapp.py
BASE_URI='https://example.com'
OTHER_API_KEY='abc123itsasecret'
```

**config.py**

```py
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config(object):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite:///"
    API_URL = os.environ.get('BASE_URI') + "/api/v1"
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('OTHER_API_KEY')
```

**test_file.py**

```py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import config

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class TestTheThing(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        load_dotenv(os.path.join(basedir, '.flaskenv'))
        app.config.from_object(config.Config)
        app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite://"
        db.create_all()
        self.client = app.test_client()
```

In the console after running `python -m unittest myapp.test_file`

```
File "/../../package/config.py", line 29, in Config
    'API_URL': os.environ.get('BASE_URI') + 'api/v1/',
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading more, I realized that I needed to load the variables in my config file, *not* in the test runner. Adding `load_dotenv` to the top of the config file allowed tests to run.

**config.py**

```py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

load_dotenv(os.path.join(basedir, '.flaskenv'))
# rest of file
```

I spent time trying to figure out where the crash was happening. I added a breakpoint inside `setUp` that never got hit, so it had to be earlier in the execution.

Reading the stack trace more carefully, it was caused by importing `app` at the top of the test file. When the app is imported, it tries to pull all the variables in before it could call `load_dotenv` inside `setUp`. Loading environment variables before the config object was loaded into the Flask object cleared it up.